# Extract a number from string in batch script

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I've been struggling to write a script that will find the drive index number from other properties of the drive. The script is as follows:

```
@echo off
REM batch file to load Veracrypt
Set "driveIndex="
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('wmic diskdrive where "model ='WD Elements 1078 USB Device'" get index') do SET driveIndex=%%a & goto reportLetter

:reportLetter
if not defined driveIndex (
echo Error Occured!
pause
exit
) else (
echo \Device\Harddisk%driveIndex:~0%\Partition3
pause
exit
)
```

However, the output of the script is `\Device\Harddisk1 \Partition3`. I tried for a long long time but could get the script to give the following output: `\Device\Harddisk1\Partition3`.

Could anyone tell me how to correct the code to get the required output?

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Comment: The problem is that wmic is outputting an additional blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
DO SET "driveIndex=%%a"
```

Your line

```
... do set driveIndex=%%a & goto ...
```

is interpreted as `set driveIndex=%%a<space>& goto ...`, this is, where the additional space in `\Device\Harddisk1 \Partition3` comes from.

Of course you could write:

```
... do set driveIndex=%%a& goto ...
```

but the better syntax is:

```
... do set "driveIndex=%%a" & goto ...
```

which eliminates any unintended spaces.

Note1: `set` is very picky with spaces. `set var = hello` creates a variable named `var<space>` with the value `<space>hello<space>`.

Note2:

`set var="value"` sets the value to `"value"`

`set "var=value"`sets the value to `value`. This syntax gives you full (and visible) control to the variable name and it's value.

Comment: best answer until now, but you really should explain why this works better to make your answer a good one.

Comment: I thought more of an explanation for the quotes with the `set`command to avoid the space at the end of the variable - which is the problem in the question.

Comment: It worked! I don't know why those quotations worked, and I intend to find out, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET DRIVE_INDEX=

FOR /F "usebackq skip=1" %%i IN (`wmic diskdrive where "model = 'HGST HTS725050A7E630 ATA Device'" get index`) DO (
    IF "!DRIVE_INDEX!" EQU "" (SET DRIVE_INDEX=%%i)
)

ECHO DRIVE_INDEX is set to %DRIVE_INDEX%
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is returning a blank %drive_index%

Comment: I revised the answer, please try it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is that WMIC output is Unicode.

I'd try

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('wmic diskdrive where "model ='WD Elements 1078 USB Device'" get index^|more') do SET driveIndex=%%a & goto reportLetter
```

where the `^|more` converts to ANSI. The caret escapes the pipe to tell `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed.

Comment: `|more` does not change anything for me. (WIN8.1)